# how to receive large json data from C# and pass it to ajax

Tags: .net, ajax

I’m trying to receive large amount of json data from c# and pass it to ajax caller but i received  error internal server error 500 .  i receive the information from sql server as json and all the information received very fine with C#.json result contains  1203521 characters.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static dynamic GetAttendanceIssuesOfEmployees()
    {

        string res ="";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("getAttendanceIssuesOfEmployees", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isJson",1);
           com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {


                res = rdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
            }
            return res;

        }  

    }
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "AttendanceIssuesOfEmployees.aspx/GetAttendanceIssuesOfEmployees",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{}",
          success: function (data) {
              console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

internal server error 500.

Comment: I'm assuming it doesn't even hit the controller method, am I right?

Comment: no it does and it receive all the information but it does not pass it to ajax

Comment: i tried this  <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967294"/> but it did not work and i tried this <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>   and it did not work

Comment: Have you tried removing `dataType: "json",` and in the controller method, returning this: `return Json(new {res = res} );` and then in the success you can access res by the following, `data.res`